# Password field in Mongoose Schema with Social Auth using Passportjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, mongoose-schema

I'm developing an application where I will integrate Social Authentication using facebook and twitter. I am using Passportjs for it. Also, there would be an option for local login/signup as well. My user schema for local login/signup looks like this

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true}}

});
```

**Should I keep password entity as `required: true` even when there is a use case of user authenticating through facebook and password entity is left blank?**

What possible solution can be implemented here??

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you can do is that you should remove required field from your model as during social auth password is not required. But when a user tries to perform a local sign-in then you can put a required attribute in your HTML form and can perform checks from your backend APIs to see if password is correct or not.